# Why do start and end dates in views appear the same but are not in content?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

When adding fields to a view I have two entries for date.
One for the start date and one for the end date.
However in my view they are both the start date.
I check my content and it shows differing values for start and end dates.

Why does views not render the end date?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have a single date field in your content that you have set with an end date but in your view you have set this with two different fields. Instead you should edit the view and click the first date field and check the formatter settings to be one that includes start and end dates.